# Python - Multiple LIKE arguments in sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

I am trying to create a search function in tkinter from a sql table.

```
        for konto in sql_konto_search(db_file, "kontoplan", keywords):
            tv.insert('', tk.END, values=((konto[konto_q][0], konto[konto_q][1]), konto[konto_q][2]), tags=('fg', 'fs', 'bg', 'anch'))
            konto_q += 1
        if not keywords:
            tv.delete(*tv.get_children())
            tv_index()
```

Here is my SQL code (function). I am trying to create a query that is searching for multiple keywords - but it is not working that well.

```
def sql_konto_search(db_file, table, keywords):
keywords_split = keywords.split()
keywords_list = []
for keyword in keywords_split:
    keywords_list.append(keyword)
ant_que = len(keywords_list)
keywords_list = tuple(keywords_list)
try:
    rows = []
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    xq = 0
    for ant_q in range(ant_que):
        cur.execute(f"SELECT konto, konto_t, beskrivelse FROM {table} WHERE konto_t LIKE ('%{keywords_list[xq]}%') OR beskrivelse LIKE ('%{keywords[xq]}%')")
        xq += 1
        rows.append(cur.fetchall())
    return rows
except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

As you can see "keywords" are user input keywords - and I want to search for every single word.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use f-strings to compose queries! That makes your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: So as you type, you would search?

Comment: Yes @Sujay, but every space ( ) returns a new keyword.

Comment: ```.strip()``` to be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want something like this to properly compose a single SQL query from your keyword search string.

This also properly uses parameter substitution, so your program is no longer vulnerable to SQL injection issues. (I recommend reading the [sqlite3 module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3); search for "Never do this".)

```
import sqlite3


def sql_konto_search(db_file, table, keywords):
    # Get an unique set of keywords from the string
    keywords_set = set(keyword.strip() for keyword in keywords.split())

    # Initialize a list for the where clauses we'll OR together
    where_clauses = []
    # Initialize a list for the `?` parameter placeholders.
    parameters = []

    for keyword in keywords_set:
        # If the keyword is empty, skip it.
        if not keyword:
            continue
        # Add a parenthesized fragment for the search with two parameter placeholders...
        where_clauses.append("(konto_t LIKE ? OR beskrivelse LIKE ?)")

        # ... so add two parameters.
        keyword_wildcard = f"%{keyword}%"
        parameters.append(keyword_wildcard)
        parameters.append(keyword_wildcard)

    # Compose the final query. Start with the select...
    query_fragments = [f"SELECT konto, konto_t, beskrivelse FROM {table}"]
    if where_clauses:
        # and if there are where clauses, add the WHERE
        # and join the clauses with ORs (they're already parenthesized above)
        query_fragments.append(" WHERE ")
        query_fragments.append(" OR ".join(where_clauses))

    # Join the fragments into a single SQL statement...
    sql = "".join(query_fragments)

    print(sql, parameters)  # Just so you can see what happens.

    # ... and execute it.
    with sqlite3.connect(db_file) as db:
        cur = db.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql, parameters)
        return cur.fetchall()
```